# How do I trigger the instance of my ng-class with my getter/setter?

Tags: angular, service, getter-setter, ng-class

I have a menu and when I click on a menu item a "is-active" class is applied via ng-class. The class applies a different color to the menu item to make it clear the menu item is selected. Each menu item generates different content. When you click that content the route changes and the is-active class is lost because the component is destroyed.

I'm using a getter/setter to try and store the active state in my service, but I don't know how to make sure it works with just the appropriate menu item. I'm using an object and looping through each item so when I try to set the ng-class to the getter/setter all the menu items get the class instead of just the one I clicked. How can I change my code so that the getter/setter is set to just the menu item I clicked?

```
// template
<header class="tabs__header">
    <div
        class="tab"
        *ngFor="let e of entities"
        [ngClass]="{'is-active': e.active || showImage }" 
        (click)="setActive(e)">
        <button>
            <h3>{{e.name}}</h3>
        </button>
    </div>
</header>

// component
entities = [
    {'name': "Doctors"},
    {'name': "Hospitals"},
    {'name': "Pharmacies"}
];

get showImage(): boolean {
    return this.entityService.showImage;
}

set showImage(value: boolean) {
    this.entityService.showImage = value
}

setActive(e) {
    this.entities.forEach(function(e) {
        if(e['active'] === true) {
            e['active'] = false
        }
    });
    e.active = true
    this.showImage = !this.showImage;
}

// service

showImage: boolean;
```

Comment: Can we see the definition of the `Entity` class? I assume that `entities` is an array of `Entity` objects.

Comment: Yes, it's just an array of objects storing my menu.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `showImage` is a property of your component, so setting it to `true` means that the expression `e.active || showImage` is *always* true for every repeated item, regardless of what `e.active` equates to. `showImage` isn't scoped to each repeated entity; it's one single property being bound to all of them.

Your getter and setter here are doing essentially nothing; you'd get the same result by binding the ngClass to `"{'is-active': e.active || entityService.showImage }"`

Also, you have the parameter `e` in your `setActive` function shadowed in your `forEach` expression. That might screw things up.

You didn't really state what you're trying to accomplish in the end, so I don't have an answer to get you there, but you mentioned somehow getting a `showImage` scoped for each entity.

If I make a big fat assumption and presume that you're trying to show an image when the entity is inactive and something else when active, that can be accomplished a little differently:

```
// template
<header class="tabs__header">
    <div
        class="tab"
        *ngFor="let e of entities"
        [class.is-active]="e.active" 
        (click)="setActive(e)">

        <button>
            <img src="someSrc" *ngIf="!e.active" />
            <h3 *ngIf="e.active">{{e.name}}</h3>
        </button>
    </div>
</header>


// component
setActive(e) {
    this.entities.forEach(s => s.active = false);
    e.active = true

    // this would essentially toggle showImage on each click. 
    // is this intended?
    // this.entityService.showImage = !this.entityService.showImage;
}
```

That would basically toggle between the image and the is-active/h3 element on each click.

If you wanted to track a `showImage` property on each `Entity`, you'd need to add that property to the `Entity` type and control it that way. If that's the case, this would be a good situation to wrap up these repeated `Entities` in their own components, with intended behaviors scoped to them.

If I was completely wrong here in assuming what you're trying to do, sorry. Just let me know.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I’m trying to keep the active state on my menu item when the user navigates to another page. I was trying to use a getter/setter to store that information when I navigate to another page. The menu item exists on both pages the user can navigate to.

Comment: In that case, you wouldn't need to retail that information in a service or anywhere separate from the component. You could just use a `router-outlet` to route *under* the nav bar without destroying the nav bar itself.

Comment: I don't think that would work either because the menu doesn't exist on every page. It's a menu for a specific component that only exist on a couple of pages.

Comment: That can still be accomplished with the router. Lump all the components with the menu into a module, and then route to the module as a child.

Comment: Yea, I just added the active class based on the queryParams. Thank you.